# Show / Not show storyboard image in code while adjusting constraints

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

So, I have the following setup in storyboard:

[storyboard image showing the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWtl2.png)

The code is setup so that that image is an optional. As it stands, when the object passed to this view controller doesn't have an image in it, the image becomes hidden. The problem is the gap that remains between paragraph1 and paragraph2. I want to have it so that if the image isn't in the object being passed to this viewController, then paragraph1 and paragraph2 come close to each other.

If you need any more info about the setup, I'm all ears(well, eyes, but hey...) Any direction would help. Thanks.

Comment: a possible way is to set the image to be the same as the background color when there isn't a image so that it occupies the same space

Comment: Thing is, when there's no image, the image view is still in the storyboard Even  though it's hidden; so it takes up the same space as it would if there was an image being displayed between the two paragraphs and since it's hidden, there's a white space there. I want to NOT have that space... I want the two paragraphs to come next to each other when there's no image.

Comment: Add an outlet for the Image's "Height" constraint. Then when there is no image, set the constant of the constraint to 0 and set the image as hidden.

Comment: ooops misread your question. how are you positioning your ui elements? if the constraints are not set in relation to the image then this might be causing the gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cell subclass, add an outlet to the UIImageView height constraint. When you configure the cell, e.g. in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, check if the image is nil, like this:

    `if let _ = cell.myImageView.image {
        cell.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = xx // put your image height here
    } else {
        cell.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0 // give the imageView a height of 0
    }`

Comment: Why did I not think of this... Grrr... Alright. I'll give it a try and tell you how it goes. Thanks for he reply!

Comment: Thanks mate! Marked it.